# Tile Master Game - Random tiles to ensure resolver, regardless of the layout

Tags: javascript, html

How to play:

There can be multiple layers stacked on top of each other.
Tiles of the lower layer will be disabled if they overlap, It will be enabled if the tile above is lost.
Pick up three same elements from layout and eliminate them.

How to random tiles to ensure resolver, regardless of the layout.

I want a algorithm to resolver this problem.

Comment: You can do this by using a combination of algorithms. The first step is to generate the tiles randomly, ensuring that the puzzle is solvable. Then create a mechanism to remove three same elements from the layout.

Comment: Thank, i can generate the tiles randomly ensuring that the puzzle is solvable. But i don't know how to shuffle tiles  regardless of the layout.

Comment: One possible to use is using [Fisher-Yates (or Knuth)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) to shuffle the tiles.